# How can I make python code cleaner, optimized, and efficient?

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, metadata, extract

I wrote a program in python 3 that extracts the metadata from the image and does multiple things with this information. One of the features is that it would extract the GPS coordinates from the metadata and use google map's static API to draw up a map of the location.

Everything works fine but I wrote this very messy code to extract the coordinates from the data found. How can I clean up this code make it more efficient? I would also appreciate any tips for writing better code.

Thanks in advance.

**Here's a example of the input data: (Shortened to save space)**

```
    EXIF BrightnessValue: 10
    EXIF ColorSpace: sRGB
    EXIF ComponentsConfiguration: YCbCr
    EXIF Contrast: Normal
    EXIF CustomRendered: Normal
    EXIF DateTimeDigitized: 2006:10:11 09:37:52
    EXIF DateTimeOriginal: 2006:10:11 09:37:52
    EXIF DigitalZoomRatio: 0
    EXIF ExifImageLength: 768
    EXIF ExifImageWidth: 1024
    EXIF ExifVersion: 0221
    EXIF ExposureBiasValue: 0
    EXIF ExposureMode: Auto Exposure
    EXIF ExposureProgram: Aperture Priority
    EXIF ExposureTime: 1/800
    EXIF FNumber: 71/10
    EXIF Flash: Flash did not fire, compulsory flash mode
    GPS GPSAltitude: 0
    GPS GPSAltitudeRef: 0
    GPS GPSLatitude: [33, 51, 2191/100]
    GPS GPSLatitudeRef: S
    GPS GPSLongitude: [151, 13, 1173/100]
    GPS GPSLongitudeRef: E
    GPS GPSVersionID: [0, 0, 2, 2]
    Image Artist:  
    Image Copyright:  
    Image DateTime: 2006:10:11 09:37:52
    Image ExifOffset: 346
    Image GPSInfo: 946
    Image ImageDescription: KONICA MINOLTA DIGITAL CAMERA
    Image Make: Konica Minolta Camera, Inc.
    Image Model: DiMAGE A2
    Image Orientation: Horizontal (normal)
```

**Here is what my code does (output):**

```
    ['33', '51', '2191/100', 'S', '151', '13', '1173/100', 'E']
```

It extracts the GPSLatitude, GPSLatitudeRef, GPSLongitude, and GPSLongitudeRef and assigns them to a single list in that order show above. (The order is important because other functions rely on the order of this list)

**Code Snippet:**

```
def coordinates_extractor():
    out = []

    lat1 = []
    lon1 = []

    lat2 = []
    lon2 = []

    lat3 = []
    lon3 = []

    lat4 = []
    lon4 = []

    ALL = []

    for tag in tags.keys():
        if tag not in ("JPEGThumbnail", "TIFFThumbnail", "EXIF MakerNote"):
            out += [("%s: %s" % (tag, tags[tag]))]
        out = sorted(out)

    for i in out:
        if "GPSLatitudeRef:" in i:
            lat1 += [i]
        if "GPSLatitude:" in i:
            lat1 += [i]

    for i in out:
        if "GPSLongitudeRef:" in i:
            lon1 += [i]
        if "GPSLongitude:" in i:
            lon1 += [i]

    for i in lat1:
        lat2 += i.split()

    del lat2[0]
    del lat2[0]
    del lat2[3]
    del lat2[3]

    for i in lat2:
        if "[" in i:
            lat3 += [i.replace("[", "")]
            continue
        if "]" not in i:
            lat3 += [i]
        if "]" in i:
            lat3 += [i.replace("]", "")]

    for i in lat3:
        if "," in i:
            lat4 += [i.replace(",", "")]
        if "," not in i:
            lat4 += [i]

    for i in lon1:
        lon2 += i.split()

    del lon2[0]
    del lon2[0]
    del lon2[3]
    del lon2[3]

    for i in lon2:
        if "[" in i:
            lon3 += [i.replace("[", "")]
            continue
        if "]" not in i:
            lon3 += [i]
        if "]" in i:
            lon3 += [i.replace("]", "")]

    for i in lon3:
        if "," in i:
            lon4 += [i.replace(",", "")]
        if "," not in i:
            lon4 += [i]

    LATANDLONG = lat4 + lon4

    return LATANDLONG
```

Example tags are extracted from: http://ptforum.photoolsweb.com/ubbthreads.php?ubb=download&Number=1024&filename=1024-2006_1011_093752.jpg

Comment: Questions about improving functional code are best suited to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this. I included a mocked dict object, to make it easy to run without the image. You need only remove this and replace it with the real `tags` object provided by the`exifread` library, that I believe you are using.

```
# mock dictionary because I dont have your image
tags = {}
tags['GPS GPSLatitude'] =  [33, 51, 2191/100]
tags['GPS GPSLatitudeRef'] = 'S'
tags['GPS GPSLongitude'] = [151, 13, 1173/100]
tags['GPS GPSLongitudeRef'] = 'E'

out = []
wantedtags = ('GPS GPSLatitude', 'GPS GPSLatitudeRef', 'GPS GPSLongitude', 'GPS GPSLongitudeRef')

for tag in wantedtags:
    try:
        val = tags[tag]
        if isinstance(val, list):
            out.extend(map(str, val))
        else:
            out.append(val)
    except KeyError:
        print('Key %s does not exists' % tag)

print(out)
```

One note though is the output is not the same as your expected output exactly. The reason being that the literals `2191/100` and `1173/100` are evaluated at runtime to be division statements and in the list are seen as `21` & `11` for python 2 and `21.91` & `11.73` for python 3. Use `from __future__ import division` in python 2 to get the more precise division results.

Is the behaviour from `exifread` different? i.e. Does it store this value in some other form that maintains the fractional value and not just a plain old int?

I ran your own code against my own mocked dictionary and the output was exactly the same as my version.